# Write access for iterators ? Or: sending values to generators of numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pass-by-reference, generator, yield

I'm new to Python's iterators, so maybe my language is not always correct.

I have a class wrapping a list of `numpy.ndarray`:

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, myList):
        self.myList = myList

    def getArrayIterator(self):
        for arr in self.myList:
            yield arr

#set list of arrays in wrapper
myList = [rand(3,3), rand(3,3), rand(3,3)]
w = wrapper(myList)
```

As I understood it, the second method returns a generator.
Now I want to use that generator to loop over the list and reset the arrays to something else:

```
for a in w.getArrayIterator():
    a = zeros((3,4))
```

I was hoping to have pass by reference semantics here, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So I tried using Python's `send()` in my `getArrayIterator` function:

```
# ...
def getArrayIterator(self):
    for arr in self.myList:
        val = (yield arr)
        if val is not None:
            arr = val
# ...
```

But that wont work either because:

```
a.send(zeros((3,4)))
  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Is there a simple solution to achieve my desired behavior?
Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT:** It has been pointed out to me, that I should provide more Information about my actual problem. The example above is of course simplified.

I have a list of lists of `numpy.ndarray` representing a tensor T encapsulated in my class. When accessing an element of T: `t_ijkl` I need to multiply the matrices stored in the list: `A(i)*B(j)*C(k)*D(l)`, first and last are row / col vectors.

So there is a set of A, a set of B, etc. Each of which belongs to a gridpoint in my application.

I now wanted to have an iterator over all gridpoints and iterators over the matrices associated with each gridpoint.

The first Idea that came to mind was to use iterators c++ style to read and write the matrices. But as agf pointed out below, this is not really a feasible approach. So I think I'll use the different iterators just for read access and specialized setter methods to set new values for the matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is a good practice. Maybe there's a better way to achive what you need. Could you provide an example of your input array and desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure either:D
The whole class represents a Matrix Product State, which is some kind of decomposition scheme for tensors, where each element in the tensor is represented as a product of associated matrices. So for example, if I have a tensor of order 3 and I want to access element_ijk I actually do t_ijk = A(i) * A(j) * A(k) where the first and last matrix are row and column vectors. Each index i,j,k... belongs to a physical index on a lattice and the A matrices are stored in a list of lists of np.ndarray. So what I actually need two things: ...

Comment: ... First: I want to iterate over the sets of matrices on the individual physical grid points. And second: I want to independently iterate over over the individual matrices on a given site.

Comment: You could [edit] your question and put the new information there, this way they'll be more clear. Seriously, at least leave a note, but given the "complexity" of your actual request I'd say that you'll have better chances with a new question. Usually newbies tend to split in two their probelm, and they ask how to make their solution work, just ask what you need :)

Comment: @Rik Poggi: oh, I wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing it out. I'll do that in a few minutes. agf's answer actually solved my problem, or at least  put me in the right direction. I'll attach my approach and actual problem to the question later. Does that work ?

Comment: Edit to question are to provide more information of improve them for this question. So the background of this question belong in the question, but if you built your own solution you could post it among the answers, it's ok to answer your own question. If instead you're moving one, then I'd suggest to open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a simplified example, because with the class you have there seems to be no reason not to just use a normal list.

When you do

```
name = somelist[0]
name = 'other'
```

you're pointing the name `name` at the object at the first index in `somelist`, then pointing the name `name` at the object `'other'`. You're not ever pointing `somelist[0]` at `'other'`.

So in addition to `send`, you need to actually assign to the list:

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, myList):
        self.myList = myList

    def getArrayIterator(self):
        for i, arr in enumerate(self.myList):
            yarr = (yield arr)
            if yarr is not None:
                self.myList[i] = yarr

#set list of arrays in wrapper
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
w = wrapper(myList)
witer = w.getArrayIterator()
try:
    a = next(witer)
    for i in range(6, 11):
        print a,
        a = witer.send(i)
except StopIteration:
    pass
print
print w.myList
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, alltough:
Seems like the AttributeError I got was because I accessed the already dereferenced Iterator in my for loop and that's why you wrote the loop explicitly.

Is there a neater way of doing this ? The whole try catch construct kind of defeats the purpose of me using iterators: Which would be clean code, instead of loads of loops and indices.

Comment: @MischaObrecht I think because of the way `send` works you're going to have to use the `try` / `except` block. You still haven't elucidated why you don't just use a `list` -- you don't have to access it by indicies, you show right in your class you can iterate over it. I don't understand why you're making things complicated, or why you need to replace items white you're iterating over it.

Comment: Oh, and yes, it is a simplified example, cf. my commentary to the initial question above if you're interested. Thx
If I only use the list, the code sooner or later becomes a horrible mess of indices like list[site_index][first_physicalIndex][secondPhysicalIndex][rowIdx, colIdx] ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you want to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, myList):
        self.myList = myList    

    def __iter__(self):
        for arr in self.myList:
            yield arr    

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.myList[key]   

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.myList[key] = value
```

Usage:

```
for index, arr in enumerate(w):
    same_arr = w[index]
    w[index] = zeros((3,4))
```

There are lots of other useful functions that you can implement if you think it will make your life easier. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) on emulating container types.

Comment: This doesn't explain `send` and just works _exactly_ like you were using a `list` rather than a user-defined class.

Comment: @agf My understanding of the question was that the purpose of the wrapper class was to intercept calls to the numpy array and do something with them rather than just learn about generators. I thought this as the class isn't needed if you just want to play with generators.

Comment: Could be. I didn't guess at his reason, but that makes sense.

Comment: First I wasn't sure how the send() method works, and that has been nicely explained above.
As I'm now thinking further about the problem, your idea using getters and setters is not all that bad. Although I will have to use some dedicateed setMatrix() methods, because setitem and getitem are already overloaded for somtehing else.

Answer (score -1):

You can only read value using generator (yield keyword) not write it

Comment: I know, that's why I tried the __send()__ mechanism, which didn't work either.
(I just wanted to make sure, everybody gets the idea of what I want to do, with the first half of my post.)

Comment: This hasn't been true since Py2.5: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-342-new-generator-features